# Searching for FAQ or Tutorial

Tags: server

I am very new to this and trying not to ask too many frustrating questions, but although I can find a lot of suggestions on here for FAQ's and Tutorials, I cannot find any that have been created.

I have used Google - but having found a few million results, my question is:

**Is there a link to a good resource on here for people very new to ubuntu please - and if not, is there a specific resource elsewhere, suggested for "ubuntu beginners" ?**

Thank you.

Edit: I tried to add ***FAQ***, ***Tutorial*** and ***Beginner*** as tags but now realise that they are not "popular tags". I looked at the ones which *were* popular but they didn't seem too relevant - so have left tags field empty other than "server". If someone with sufficient reputation,thinks they could be useful though, then please feel free to add them (and delete this edit), it might be a question which other beginners might welcome answers to.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a good question for [ubuntu.se]. You can ask for specific problems you have, but questions asking for general lists of external resources aren't on-topic here.

Comment: Feel free to ask about any specific issue you are encountering if you cannot find information after searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no, I don’t think there are such tutorials here.

What you’ll find is a great resource when you have a specific question - if you encounter a problem, do a bit of research to try to resolve it, if you can’t then post a question and someone (or lots of people) will try to help you.

To get going, there are tutorials at Ubuntu.com (just Google ‘install Ubuntu’ to find the pages).

Once installed, there are various online tutorials you’ll be able to find, and you’ll find a desktop help feature in Ubuntu - it’s probably in favourites on the left (a big ? icon), or click on the grid at the bottom left, open utilities and it’s in there.

From my experience, reading just a little (literally only 5 minutes) most days from lots of resources - including some of the questions and answers on this site, also googling things like ‘Linux tips and tricks’ - was the best way to get familiar with Ubuntu. If you’re really new to it, it’s probably worth setting up as a dual boot system so you can revert back to (presumably) windows periodically if you encounter difficulties with an important function.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks Will, I will follow your guidance and see what I can learn. I appreciate you taking the time to answer - even if it was not a good question!

Comment: @Mark It probably isn’t a ‘good’ question, but in my view there are few ‘bad’ questions and this most definitely isn’t one of them. Bad questions are those that are incoherent, unrelated to a supported version of Ubuntu, or where the asker has gone to no effort themselves. None of these apply to the above so I thought it was fine. I’ve not been on au for that long though and I appreciate that some very experienced users disagree, but please don’t be put off asking a question if it would help you. Not enough people use Ubuntu and I think we need to encourage new users.